# Flex / adobe air error collection service

Tags: apache-flex, error-handling, air, error-logging, error-reporting

I have an adobe air .exe application which randomly crashes sometimes without any clear reason of the cause.

I am investigating ways in which I could run an extra service which is integrated with my app so that when it crashes it works in the same way as the windows error dialog(send error log).

Ideally the log would collect system information such as event log, CPU and ram state, running processes etc

Does anyone know of anything that does that?

Closest thing I have found is airbrake

Thanks

Comment: +1 for best logging technique in run-time environment, i keen to know how to implement this technique.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `UncaughtErrorEvent`, which will allow you to listen for any thrown errors that are unhandled. You can then send the data to some service (Google Analytics, maybe). There are two problems with this:

- You don't actually have access to much system information in Flash/AIR, only the limited information supplied by the `Capabilities` and `System` class.

  - This can be supplemented with an ANE that provides more information (I don't have any on-hand, though I have seen a few in the past)
- It does not work if the error occurs lower than the AIR runtime. So if something goes wrong in an ANE or in AIR itself, you won't see an error, it will just crash.

Alternatively, you could use something like the [Crashlytics ANE](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Crashlytics) (mobile only, sorry) from Freshplanet which seems to handle this a lot better (this is for hard crashes only, I believe, and won't provide any information from your AIR app itself, since it is lower level than that).

Documentation:

- [`UncaughtErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html)
- [`System`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html)
- [`Capabilities`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am already doing that, I was thinking more of something that I can run in tandem with teh adobe air application so that it detects whether the app has crashed and sends both the application log file, together with other information, such as the Windows Event Log, Running Processes etc.